# JFrame.getInsets weird value

Tags: java, swing, java-11

AdoptOpenJDK 11 on Windows 10. JFrame descendant constructor:

```
getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds()
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=2560,height=1440]

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration())
java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=40,right=0]

set*Size(new Dimension(2560, 1400));

pack();

getSize();
java.awt.Dimension[width=2560,height=1400]

getInsets();
java.awt.Insets[top=31,left=8,bottom=8,right=8]

getContentPane().getSize()
java.awt.Dimension[width=2544,height=1361]
```

... and yet the window does not cover full desktop space minus the task bar (because of those extra insets of 8). Why?

Example code using my answer:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public final class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public CustomPanel(Dimension d) {
            setMinimumSize(d);
            setPreferredSize(d);
            setMaximumSize(d);
            //this is just an example, there is custom layout code here, not using Swing, but it needs Dimension d to work
        }

    }

    public TestFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = getGraphicsConfiguration();
        Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();
        Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);
        Dimension expectedFrameSize = new Dimension(screenBounds.width - screenInsets.left - screenInsets.right, screenBounds.height - screenInsets.top - screenInsets.bottom);

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
        Dimension frameSize = getSize();
        Insets frameInsets = getInsets();
        setVisible(false);
        Dimension contentSize = new Dimension(frameSize.width - frameInsets.left - frameInsets.right, frameSize.height - frameInsets.top - frameInsets.bottom);
        getContentPane().add(new CustomPanel(contentSize));

        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);

        System.out.println("screenBounds " + screenBounds);
        System.out.println("screenInsets " + screenInsets);
        System.out.println("expectedFrameSize " + expectedFrameSize);
        System.out.println("frameSize " + frameSize);
        System.out.println("frameInsets " + frameInsets);
        System.out.println("contentSize " + contentSize);
        System.out.println("assert expectedFrameSize == frameSize " + expectedFrameSize.equals(frameSize));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I would like to be able to calculate `Dimension dimension` without making the window temporarily visible. But it's impossible to arrive at correct sizes using methods available in the JDK:

```
getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds()
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration())
```

Comment: The frame’s insets are part of the frame, so it *does* cover the desktop space. What do you actually want? a) [maximize the frame](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)), b) [a borderless window](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean)), or c) [a fullscreen window](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow(java.awt.Window))?

Comment: Currently the frame is not taking entire desktop space, like a maximized windows does. On the left, right and at the bottom there are bands few pixels wide (I guess 8 pixels wide) where windows underneath it are visible. I also need to have the size of content pane calculated before showing the frame, as on that size many things depend. So I want to calculate maximized size, and set it to that size, without actually maximizing. So despite it saying the frame is 2560 wide, it's not as I can see other windows in those bands, and my monitor is definitely 2560 wide.

Comment: The operating system (or its desktop) decides how to represent borders. If it decides to have a semi-transparent shadow that it counts as part of the border, then that’s the way it is. Again, it’s not clear what you want. If you want the same behavior as a maximized frame, then why don’t you maximize it? If you don’t want to have borders, why don’t you turn off borders? If you only want to know the content pane’s size before showing, why don’t you use the code you’ve posted yourself, which demonstrates that the size is known after `pack()`, before showing the frame?

Comment: See the bands on the left, right and bottom of my nominally "maximized" window: https://imgur.com/5LD6j8c (Firefox is showing from beneath). I want my window to take all of that space. Yet, I want it to have all the normal borders.

Comment: Then call `setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`. Or provide a comprehesible explanation why using the API that is precisely for that purpose, is not an option to you.

Comment: I need to know the size of the content pane it will have with maximized window, before making the frame visible.

Comment: `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); setVisible(true); System.out.println(getSize()); System.out.println(getInsets()); System.out.println(getContentPane().getSize());` The numbers are correct only if setVisible is used before getting size. And what's funny is that `getContentPane().getSize()` has the same value like in my method, except this time frame covers full desktop. So it's almost like Java is cheated by the system, thinking it has different size than it really has.

Comment: So your problem is that `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` does not affect the frame’s size immediately when the frame is not visible? The size is the screen size minus the screen insets, but also minus the title bar (but not the top border), whose size does not have a query API. If that’s yo problem, you should have said that in the first place, instead of trying to emulate `setExtendedState`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221268/discussion-between-morvael-and-holger).

Answer (score 2):

The insets of a frame describe size of the window decoration, which may include semi-transparent borders. On Microsoft Windows, there’s also a connection to the fact that window borders used to be 8 pixels thick in earlier versions.

When you maximize the window, its bounds will be set in a way that these insets are outside the visible areas, except for some parts of the title bar, which stays visible. To make predictability even worse, the title bar changes its layout when the window has been maximized, having less margin space.

But when you are looking for a Windows-only solution, the legacy aspects may help here. Consider the article “[Why does a maximized window have the wrong window rectangle?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120326-00/?p=8003)”. As it explains, the window will always be at (-*n*,-*n*) and have (2*n*×2*n*) more than the actual visible area, for the border size *n*, for compatibility with old software. But, as it also explains, the maximized mode is special, as these borders are always cut off, so they do not show up in other monitors nor over the task bar.

That’s why it is impossible to emulate the same behavior by setting bounds only. Not only does the rendition of the title bar differ, you would also make parts of the window appear in other monitors on multi-monitor systems and over the task bar.

So, using that knowledge, you can predict the content pane size:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Max");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

Timer t = new Timer(1000, ev -> System.out.println("actual size is "
    +frame.getContentPane().getWidth()+" x "+frame.getContentPane().getHeight()));
t.setRepeats(false);
t.start();

Rectangle scrBounds = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();
Insets scrInsets = frame.getToolkit().getScreenInsets(frame.getGraphicsConfiguration());
Insets winInsets = frame.getInsets();

int width = scrBounds.width - scrInsets.left - scrInsets.right;
int height = scrBounds.height - scrInsets.top - scrInsets.bottom
                              - winInsets.top + winInsets.bottom;

System.out.println("content pane size will be "+width+" x "+height);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

This assumes that the historical border thickness is the same for all edges, so we can use the `bottom` size to determine the top size with the title bar size, so `top - bottom` gives us the remaining title bar size.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems it's a general windows thing, and I can take into account those 8,8,8,8 extra insets.

Comment: I reduced the hardcoded assumptions by only assuming that the particular border has the same size for `top` and `bottom`, which seems to be fixed in the windows API, as I see only a single value for border height in the `tagWINDOWINFO` structure. So `top - bottom` is the size of the title bar, which is the only remaining thing that reduces the usable size of the content pane in a maximized window.

Comment: So best way to approach this would be to query Windows via native code, to get that magic 8.

Comment: I’ve found `frame.getToolkit().getDesktopProperty("win.frame.captionHeight")`, which gives the size of the title bar, except for a 1px border. But I don’t know whether that border is always 1px or needs another property to query. Which brings us back to square one.

Comment: Meanwhile on linux windows hack doesn't work, yet still there are fake 5 px borders added to frame insets :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently maximized frame has size larger than actual screen, and frame insets include 8,8,8,8 pixels (on my Windows) of which some are outside actual frame. The only way to get actual frame size that is used for maximized window is to make it visible for a while. In the end I resorted to this cheat:

```
      setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      setVisible(true);
      Dimension size = getSize();
      Insets insets = getInsets();
      setVisible(false);
      dimension = new Dimension(size.width - insets.left - insets.right, size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom);
```

This allows me to find out what will be the dimension of the frame's content pane with frame taking all of desktop space (screen minus taskbar). And `setResizable(false)` has to be called only after final `setVisible(true)`.

See if those numbers make sense for you:

screen bounds `java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=2560,height=1440]`

screen insets `java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=40,right=0]`

frame size `java.awt.Dimension[width=2576,height=1416]`

frame insets `java.awt.Insets[top=31,left=8,bottom=8,right=8]`

calculated dimension `java.awt.Dimension[width=2560,height=1377]`

Frame size is larger than screen space (screen bounds minus screen insets) by 16 in each direction. And those extra pixels are included in frame insets, even though they are not in the frame.

Comment: I need the dimension of the content pane, because it is used to scale and layout elements inside said content pane, which come from a legacy system that used fixed positioning. The task is very simple, find out the dimension of a content pane of a maximized frame before showing that frame. That's it. And it seems it's currently impossible, plus various bounds, sized and insets methods show weird values (for example maximized frame is larger than screen size).

Comment: Posted example that works using my answer. But I want dimension without flashing the window.

Comment: The problem is I can't use screen bounds and insets to determine frame size and then content size, because maximized frame is actually larger than screen and frame insets include that extra space taken by frame outside screen. Isn't that strange?

Comment: See my requirement - I need to provide size for custom layout manager inside the content pane. My reasons are my own, but IMHO it I should be able to arrive at correct numbers without resorting to checking visible window:
`screenBounds java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=2560,height=1440]

screenInsets java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=40,right=0]

expectedFrameSize java.awt.Dimension[width=2560,height=1400]

frameSize java.awt.Dimension[width=2576,height=1416]

frameInsets java.awt.Insets[top=31,left=8,bottom=8,right=8]

contentSize java.awt.Dimension[width=2560,height=1377]`

Comment: I can't account for those 8,8,8,8 frame insets and that they will take frame size outside screen (so instead of being subtracted from content size, they increase frame size).

Comment: There is no Swing layout manager inside, so reading tutorials on them won't help me much.

Comment: Turns out frame insets are a compostion of margins and padding so to speak. And for correct calculations of internal space I need those separated.

Comment: You focus on the not important part. I simply ask why it's impossible to find out maximized frame size without showing it first. You fixated on the layout part. That's not important.

Comment: The usual way of doing Swing GUI to add all components to content pane before the frame is shown. One of my components needs to know the size it will have. So I need to calculate it. But since frameInsets contains both margin and padding I'm unable to do that properly, without showing the frame first and checking it's actual size, instead of relying on screen bounds/insets.

Comment: Whatever the problem of my code is (it's legacy code, and can't be moved to Swing layout managers now), IMHO there is something wrong with JDK API or how it works. For me a full screen frame would have size equal to screen size, not larger... And frame insets would be all inside the frame.

Comment: *...add all components to content pane before the frame is shown* - yes, but they don't have a size when they are added. When the frame is packed or made visible they are given a size. What is the problem with using a ComponentListener? When the frame is made visible the listener will be invoked and you do your calculations now that the content pane has its real size. No knowledge of the frame insets is needed.